# Write unencoded File file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

The following code needs to produce an XML file.

```
string path = @"c:\load\myFile.xml";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpFloors"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select coords.xyid as '@id', xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax,(select brief, long, img from floordesc where coords.xyid = floordesc.xyid for xml path(''),Type) as 'desc' from coords where xyid <> '' for xml path('coord'), Elements XSINIL,root('coords')", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("coords");
        da.Fill(ds, "coord");
        Response.Write(ds.GetXml());
        File.WriteAllText(path, ds.GetXml());
```

The XML should look exactly like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<coords>
<coord id="6090">
    <title>Office 6090</title>
    <xmin>10</xmin>
    <xmax>60</xmax>
    <ymin>40</ymin>
    <ymax>90</ymax>
    <desc>
        <brief>one</brief>
        <long>one more</long>
        <img>dude.jpg</img>
    </desc>
</coord>
<coord id="11090">....
```

The Response.Write code writes it out to the page correctly. However, when I try to write to a file, it gets changed to what seems like htmlencoding.

```
 &lt;coords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;&lt
```

I don't see a way to just write the same text that's rendered during response.write.  Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `ds.WriteXml(path)`. How does the output look in this instance?

Comment: The file begins thus when I choose this:<coords>
  <coord>
    <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>&lt;coords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-ins

Comment: OK, sorry, I missed the fact that you were using the `FOR XML` clause. When you do this, `ADO.NET` lets you leverage the `XmlReader`, which makes your job easier (plus avoids errors, lol). Check my answer down below.

Comment: You are xml encoding xml encoded data.  A character like `<` must be escaped to &lt.  It doesn't work for the ResponseStream either but the browser happens to know how to make sense of it.  The FOR XML clause is of course the rub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your approach. Sorry, I didn't pick up on the fact that you were using the `FOR XML` clause.

In this case, you must use the `ExecuteXmlReader`, and save the resulting output. Here's an example:

```
var xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will give this a go and let you know how it turns out.  Thanks very much!

Comment: code4life: Thanks a million!!! That did the trick.  I just couldn't see it because I kept banging my head against the same wall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ds.WriteXml(string path)` ?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf.aspx

---

If you have the option, you can bypass writing the file from .net and do it sql side

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM pubs..authors FOR XML RAW" queryout c:\myfile.xml -Sserver -Uusername -Ppassword -c -r -t
```

Reference: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=9336

Comment: Yes.  I am afraid it doesn't work for me; perhaps due to the fact I am using a query with FOR XML.  When I change that to a standard query and perform a ds.WriteXML - I get a flat XML file without the coord id= attribute or the desc children.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sean, See using the `bcp` method I mentioned in my edit.  I hope this helps.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I will take this down as well and use as well. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HtmlDecode method on your output.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

Comment: I just did this with some interesting results.  It still doesn't come back accurate though.  Sorry.  It repeats <coords>
  <coord>
    <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>... on each line. Thanks for the suggestion.